# R carry forward last observation n times by group

Tags: r, data.table, locf

This one is driving me nuts. I have a large data.table with monthly stock data. Every June I assign every stock to one of 10 portfolios based on an accounting variable. I would like to carry forward the assigned portfolio variable to the next 11 month until each stock gets assigned to a new portfolio 1 to 10 in June next year. `na.locf` is basically what I'm looking for but I am running into 2 issues:

1. Some stocks lack sufficient accounting data the next year, so they shouldn't be assigned to a portfolio in that year (i.e. portfolio variable should stay NA). But of course `na.locf` keeps carrying forward the portfolio number until there is a new one.
2. Some stocks may get delisted after e.g. 3 months so they don't have another 11 month of data.

That's why I looking for a code that carries forward the last observation a maxium of 11 times until June next year (when there is a new portfolio number).

That's the `na.locf` solution right now with the 2 issues (PERMNO is the stock identifier):

```
COMPUSTAT_CRSP_IBES1[,
                     Portfolio_Monthly := na.locf(Portfolio_Monthly, 
                                                  na.rm = FALSE),
                     by = PERMNO]
```

I tried to use `rep` but that didn't work at all:

```
COMPUSTAT_CRSP_IBES1[,
                     Portfolio_Monthly := if_else(!is.na(Portfolio_Monthly), 
                                                  rep(Portfolio_Monthly, 11), 
                                                  NA), 
                     by = PERMNO]
```

Thank's for any hints!

Comment: How would that exactly look like? I don't have a variable for the fiscal year, I only have the monthly dates. As the fiscal year runs always runs over 2 years (e.g. from June 2000 to May 2001) "by = list(PERMNO, year(Date)" won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create and/or use your fiscal year (June - May) as one of the group `by` criteria in your `na.locf` solution

```
#show data before calculations
data.frame(dat)

#demo FY calculation
dat[, FY := year(MONTH) + as.numeric(month(MONTH) >= 6)]

#actual code
dat[, Portfolio_Monthly := zoo::na.locf(Portfolio_Monthly, na.rm=FALSE),
    by=list(PERMNO, year(MONTH) + as.numeric(month(MONTH) >= 6))]

#show results
data.frame(dat)
```

## sample data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
dat <- data.table(PERMNO=rep(LETTERS[1:12], each=20), 
    MONTH=rep(seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), by="1 month", length.out=20), 12),
    Portfolio_Monthly=NA_real_)
for (i in sample(1:dat[,.N], 5)) {
    set(dat, i, 3L, rnorm(1))   
}
setorder(dat, PERMNO, MONTH)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this well-explained answer, it works perfect!